# TypeError at /admin/blogsite/articles/add/ when use markdownx

Tags: python, django, markdown

The error is coming when I use markdownx
If I used `markdownxfield()`

Then I will can't to editor the model in admin. The error is such as this:

```
TypeError at /admin/blogsite/articles/add/
```

'set' object is not reversible

```
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/blogsite/articles/add/
Django Version:     2.0
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:
```

'set' object is not reversible

```
Exception Location:     C:\Users\liano\Desktop\python\blog\blog_venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py in merge, line 114
Python Executable:  C:\Users\liano\Desktop\python\blog\blog_venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version:     3.6.2
```

So why does it happen and how to solve it?
the traceback:
Environment:Request Method: GETRequest URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/blogsite/articles/add/Django Version: 2.0Python Version: 3.6.2Installed Applications:['django.contrib.admin', 'django.contrib.auth', 'django.contrib.contenttypes', 'django.contrib.sessions', 'django.contrib.messages', 'django.contrib.staticfiles', 'blogsite', 'bootstrap3', 'markdownx', 'testapp']Installed Middleware:['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware', 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']Traceback:File "C:\Users\liano\Desktop\python\blog\blog_venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner  35.             response = get_response(request)File "C:\Users\liano\Desktop\python\blog\blog_venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)File "C:\Users\liano\Desktop\python\blog\blog_venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)File "C:\Users\liano\Desktop\python\blog\blog_venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in wrapper  574.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)File "C:\Users\liano\Desktop\python\blog\blog_venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)File "C:\Users\liano\Desktop\python\blog\blog_venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func  44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)File "C:\Users\liano\Desktop\python\blog\blog_venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py" in inner  223.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)File "C:\Users\liano\Desktop\python\blog\blog_venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in add_view  1553.         return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)File "C:\Users\liano\Desktop\python\blog\blog_venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper  62.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)File "C:\Users\liano\Desktop\python\blog\blog_venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)File "C:\Users\liano\Desktop\python\blog\blog_venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in bound_func  58.                 return func.**get**(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)File "C:\Users\liano\Desktop\python\blog\blog_venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in changeform_view  1450.             return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)File "C:\Users\liano\Desktop\python\blog\blog_venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in _changeform_view  1516.         media = self.media + adminForm.mediaFile "C:\Users\liano\Desktop\python\blog\blog_venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\helpers.py" in media  64.         media = self.form.mediaFile "C:\Users\liano\Desktop\python\blog\blog_venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py" in _media  148.             base = sup_cls.mediaFile "C:\Users\liano\Desktop\python\blog\blog_venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py" in _media  148.             base = sup_cls.mediaFile "C:\Users\liano\Desktop\python\blog\blog_venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py" in _media  148.             base = sup_cls.mediaFile "C:\Users\liano\Desktop\python\blog\blog_venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in media  460.             media = media + field.widget.mediaFile "C:\Users\liano\Desktop\python\blog\blog_venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py" in _media  148.             base = sup_cls.mediaFile "C:\Users\liano\Desktop\python\blog\blog_venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py" in _media  163.                 return m + Media(definition)File "C:\Users\liano\Desktop\python\blog\blog_venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py" in **add**  135.         combined._js = self.merge(self._js, other._js)File "C:\Users\liano\Desktop\python\blog\blog_venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py" in merge  114.         for path in reversed(list_2):Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/blogsite/articles/add/Exception Value: 'set' object is not reversible

Comment: Please provide the code that triggers this TypeError.

Comment: I have trouble same error